# PhoneGap Build cli-6.5.0 - phonegap-plugin-push - Device Ready error : typeerror: object function PushNotification(options)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

The app is throwing a error when I try to initialize the PushNotification.

Index.html

```
<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/push.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app-config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app-main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

App-config.js

```
//**** set global variables required for push notification
// google project id for application
var googleProjectID = "XXXXXXX";
// cms key - do not change
var cmsKey = "XXXXXX";
// server to send registration to and from where notifications will be send
var cmsPushServerHost = "XXXXX";
// text id of cms "Application" article
var cmsPushApplicationId = "XXXXXX";
//Push Notification, GA Plugin
var  gaPlugin, push;

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        try {
            //Push Notification
            push = PushNotification.init({ android: {senderID: googleProjectID,}, ios: {alert: "true",badge: "true",sound: "true"}});
            push.on('registration', function(data) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("app_register_id", data.registrationId);
                alert("Device Registered = " + data.registrationId);
            });
            push.on('notification', function(data) {
                alert(data.title+" Message: " +data.message);
            });
            push.on('error', function(error) {
                alert("PushNotification error : " + error);
            });
            //Google Analyics
        }
        catch(err) {
            alert("Device Ready error : " + err);
        }
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
    },
    addPushNotification: function() {
        try 
        {
            var deviceType;
            if (device.platform === 'android' || device.platform === 'Android')
            {
                deviceType = "android";
            }
            else
            {
                deviceType = "ios";
            }

            if (typeof window.localStorage.getItem('app_register_id') !== "undefined" && window.localStorage.getItem('app_register_id') !== '' && window.localStorage.getItem('app_register_id') !== null) 
            {
                if (typeof window.localStorage.getItem('settingUpdates') !== "undefined" && window.localStorage.getItem('settingUpdates') !== '' && window.localStorage.getItem('settingUpdates') !== null) 
                {
                    subscribePushNotifications(window.localStorage.getItem('app_register_id'), deviceType);
                }
                else
                {
                    unsubscribePushNotification(window.localStorage.getItem('app_register_id'), deviceType);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(err) {
            alert("addPushNotification error : " + err);
        }
    }
};
```

App-main.js

```
//App Initialize, Push Notifications
app.initialize();
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />

<!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
<!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm">
    <param name="SENDER_ID" value="XXXXXXX" />
</plugin>
```

Please can you let me know what am i doing wrong. Been struggling with this issue a bit now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: when does that error show? Build or when run application? i subspect something wrong when you add the library. I got same problem with that before

Comment: I get the error when I run the application

Comment: `push` variable only need to use in `onDeviceReady` scope, So Could you try to use `const push = PushNotification...` instead of var ?